# Can I misty step into a location I can see through Clairvoyance?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I hide in a bush that is 2000 feet from "a location familiar to [me] (a place [I] have visited or seen before)". I cast Clairvoyance to "create an invisible sensor" of sight in a portion of said location. Through the sensor, I see an unoccupied space that is under 30 feet from the sensor and because "[I] can use the chosen sense through the sensor as if [I] were in its space" I cast Misty Step to teleport to that "unoccupied space".

Answer (score 15):

#### 2000 is greater than 30.

*Misty Step* states:

> **you** teleport up to 30 feet

A location 2000 feet away is more than 30 feet from where you are, so you cannot *misty step* there. It doesn’t matter that clairvoyance allows you to see the location as if you were nearby. *Misty step* is limited by where **you** are, not where you are seeing from.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150016/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-markov-will-this-work-and-if-you-think-not-why); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 10):

### No, this will not work

*Clairvoyance* states:

> You can use the chosen sense [sight or hearing] through the sensor as if you were in its space.

You can look through it, not cast spells or do anything else through it and it doesn't count as you actually *being* there, your physical body is still 2000 feet away. *Misty Step* explicitly has a range of up to 30 feet **and** the requirement that you need to see the space you're teleporting to so it will not work, actually you won't be able to use *Misty Step* at all while looking through that sensor.

Comment: Misty Step's Range is actually Self. And I would not be casting "through it"... I am using "the chosen sense through the sensor as if [I] were in its space."

Comment: @ScottBrokke "as if you were in its space" implies that you're not actually in that space. And even assuming that your argument works, Misty Step has a verbal argument and your mouth is still 2000 ft away, the sensor doesn't allow you to speak using it.

Comment: I disagree, I believe it is the exact opposite of what you state; the line in Clairvoyance clearly states that one is to be considered in that space when using the chosen sense through the sensor.
And your idea about one's mouth is too far??? from what? there is no requirement anywhere that says in what vicinity the words must be spoken.

Comment: @ScottBrokke why did you ask this question if you already decided on an answer? you can disagree but that's just how grammar works, ask in linguistics stack if you don't believe me. You can disagree that 2+2=4 but that just makes you wrong. You're arguing with everyone who's telling you why this won't work, why don't you just go and ask your DM?

Answer (score 7):

### No. You only can use the chosen sense through the sensor

[Clairvoyance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clairvoyance) says

> When you cast the spell, you choose seeing or hearing. **You can use the chosen sense through the sensor** as if you were in its space.

That is what *clairvoyance* allows you to do: **use the chosen sense** through the sensor, as if you were in its space. The spell does not tell you that you can cast spells through the sensor, talk through the sensor, or do anything else through the sensor as if you were in its space. Nor does it tell you that you can do anything else as if you were in the sensors space, like moving or casting a spell. You also cannot cast *thunderwave* as if you were there. [Spells only do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret), and clairvoyance does not do anything but let you sense through that sensor.

Comment: I agree that one could not use the combo I am discussing with the spell Thunderwave. It does not use sight, the chosen sense. Misty Step, yes. Magic Missile, yes. Sacred Flame, no. Fire Ball, no. These spells don't "use the chosen sense".

Comment: @ScottBrokke I'm not clear where you get the idea from that you could use *any* spell through or with clairvoyance. It does not say you can use anything that has to do or uses that sense, it only says you can use that sense.

Comment: I never wrote cast "through" or "with" Clairvoyance.
The spell allows one to "use the chosen sense". No argument that I could see the spot where I intend to be, right? At that point are we not "using the sense" and thus it is "as if you were in its space." If you don't use the selected sense then the "as if you were in its space" never factors in.

Comment: it's not just seeing, the phrase is "using the sense".
Arcane Eye wouldn't do what I am describing, it says, "You mentally receive visual information from the eye, which has normal vision and darkvision out to 30 feet."

Comment: @ScottBrokke Still not sure I can follow -- why would you think you then can teleport anywhere near where the sensor is? I think you could teleport of the other side of a door with clairvoyance and misty step, but the target spot that you see through clearvoyance still needs to be within the range of misty step -- clearvoyance changes nothing about where you cast misty step or what range it has.

Comment: The range of Misty Step is Self.

and I agree that Clairvoyance does not change " where you cast misty step or what range it has." The spell description states, "You can use the chosen sense through the sensor as if you were in its space." And spells like Misty Step use the chosen sense and thus it is "as if you were in its space". I think one could also use Magic Missile in the same manner. But not Fire Ball or Thunderwave those two spells do not make use of the chosen sense... one says something like "from your finger" and the other says "out from you". They are not the same.

Comment: @ScottBrokke Where does it say that "spells use the chosen sense"? I only see it saying **you** use the chosen sense

Comment: @ScottBrokke - In real life, if you have a good camera hooked up to some VR glasses and a swivel, you can use your sense of sight through the camera as if you were there. It is also true that you can take the action "reach out two or three feet to an object that you can see." Does it follow that you can reach out and touch something within a few feet of the camera?

Answer (score 1):

[merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20if](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20if)

> 1: as it would be if
>
> It was as if he had lost his last friend.
>
> 2: as one would do if
>
> He ran as if ghosts were chasing him.

Please note that all examples of use are hypothetical non-real scenarios.

The use of "as if" is the same for the spell Clairvoyance. It allows the caster to see through that point in space as if they were in that space, but it does not actually grant them a position in that space.

And as we all know, spells only do what they say.

---

As brought up in the comments, it seems like your point of confusion may actually be the limitations of Misty Step.

The spell "Misty Step" states that "you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see".  There are two controlling points here - "up to 30 feet" and "an unoccupied space that you can see".

You may pass the second control point with Clairvoyance, but you do not pass the "up to 30 feet" control point. Both of these must be valid for you to utilize Misty Step.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation of what "as if" means, I don't think this is what OP needs to understand to see why what they want to do doesn't work

Comment: I'm not implying that the caster is physically/actually/literally in the location that the sensor occupies. It is AS IF the caster occupies the space of the sensor when the selected sense is used, ie; when using the selected sense (sight in this example) to satisfy a condition of a spell being cast.

for a counter-example, Fire Ball would not benefit from this extra sight because it makes no mention of a sense needing to be used in its description.

Comment: it's not just seeing, it's "using the sense". Arcane Eye wouldn't do what I am describing, it says, "You mentally receive visual information from the eye, which has normal vision and darkvision out to 30 feet." No mention of what space YOU occupy physically or "as if".

Comment: I think I see the point of confusion.  The spell "Misty Step" states that "you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see".  There are two controlling points here - "up to 30 feet" and "an unoccupied space that you can see".  You may pass the second control point with Clairvoyance, but you do not pass the "up to 30 feet" control point. Both of these must be valid for you to utilize Misty Step. I'm going to add this to my answer since I believe this is the point of your confusion.